# What would be correct?

Tags: grammar

What would be correct?

> The unlimited resources model utilizes a large base of resources that 
>   allows

Or

> The unlimited resources model utilizes a large base of resources that 
>   allow

Answer (score 3):

This depends on whether the subject (the thing doing the allowing) is singular or plural. In this case it depends on context.

Assuming that the thing doing the allowing is "a large base of resources", then "allow" is correct.

If the thing doing the allowing is "The unlimited resources model", then "allows" is correct.

So all you have to answer is: is this allowed thanks to the model, or the resources?

Update: As pointed out in the comments, in the case that you are talking about the model doing the allowing, the phrase also needs further rewording for clarity along the lines of:

> The unlimited resources model, utilizing a large base of resources, allows...

Comment: If it is the "*model ... allows*" meaning, then the sentence needs rewriting; for example: "The unlimited resources model, which utilizes a large base of resources, allows ..."

Comment: @JamesRandom agreed, I think I was just being charitable with the original question about the word "allows", in case the wider context was talking about the model allowing. But you're right that it would need additional rewording in that case. I'll update my answer.